# Remove duplicates based on one column and keep the rows with a specific pattern in another column in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
entry_id    num            pathway_name
hsa00010    {00010}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)
mmu00010    {00010}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Mus musculus (mouse)
rno00010    {00010}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Rattus norvegicus (rat)
hsa00011    {00011}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)
mmu00011    {00011}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Mus musculus (mouse)
rno00011    {00011}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Rattus norvegicus (rat)
rno00012    {00012}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Rattus norvegicus (rat)
```

I would like to remove duplicate rows based on column 'num' and keeping the entry_id that starts with 'hsa'

The Expected output is:

```
entry_id    num            pathway_name
hsa00010    {00010}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)
hsa00011    {00011}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)
rno00012    {00012}        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Rattus norvegicus (rat)
```

I tried to filter the rows using 'distinct on (num)' but I am unable to select the hsa entry_id. Is there a way to select rows with hsa ids and removing the duplicates?

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT ON` with an appropriate `ORDER BY` should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (entry_id) *
FROM atable
ORDER BY entry_id, NOT starts_with(entry_id, 'hsa');
```

This relies on `FALSE` < `TRUE`.